# How do I debug Node.js with Visual Studio Code inside functions?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

When I try to debug inside functions, the execution don't pass to the breakpoints.
For example, I put breakpoints in all that lines:

```
  this.exportar = function() {
    console.log('testinggggg 1');
    res.status(500).send({
      message: 'testing'
    });
    console.log('testinggggg 2');
  }
```

And the execution only pass to this line: `this.exportar = function() {`, but not to the others lines. The code don't pass to the line 106.

[image: Here is a screenshot]

What is the problem?

Comment: You have to use console.log instead of breakpoints. It will be more clearer to see the output in console

Comment: what are your debug settings?

Comment: @Owner Where I can see the result of the console.log? I using F5 key to start the server I dont know where is the console of the server. Where is? Here: https://ibb.co/hY8TGQ0 I see the debug console, but in that place dont show the console.log result, in the others tabs neither

Comment: @crystalbit Where I can see the debug settings?

Comment: How are you running your Node server? Probably, you will be starting it via a console? Or you can use the console that is available in VS code

Comment: @Owner I running my Node server with the key F5. I saw the "Debug console", "Problems" and "Output" tabs and nothing of the console.log is in that place.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your console or where are you seeing that your server is running?

Comment: @Owner This is what I see: https://ibb.co/7zDDdK4

Comment: @Owner sorry, yes, I can see the result of the console.log in that tab, I watched bad. The problem now is that the line 106 is not executed but line 105 yes: https://ibb.co/5YSpxc6

Comment: @mark thats great. Can you please tell us what is on line 105 and 105. Couldn't understand it from the code you pasted above.